# LDAP vs database for storing application configuration data

Tags: ldap

What is the best place to store Java application configuration data? (like property files, etc) The data may be modified during runtime though not very often. What are the advantages and disadvantages of both approaches?

Answer (score 0):

You have to clarify a little. Are you storing per-user configuration data? Per-install? Both?

Databases (except the NoSQL variety) are a terrible idea for storing configuration. Configuration implies key-value pairs that can change meaning/format over the lifetime of the application. Unless its a document-based database, of course. You could store entire files in blob or giant varchar() fields but this only makes it more complicated.

LDAP is designed for this sort of thing, I suppose, and its 'fast', but it has a (in my opinion) terrible API.

Have you considered using HTTP or FTP, and pulling down the files from the web using... the web?

Comment: Both kinds of data. I am more concerned about updated data being available to all application server instances in a cluster. Isn't LDAP non transactional , which means I cant be assured of reading in updated data every single time?

Comment: As far as I'm aware, some LDAP implementations are ACID conformant. Edit: confusing product names. OpenLDAP is, according to OpenLDAP.

The biggest argument against LDAP is usually the horrible API, and a lack of on-the-ground knowledge.